# Merge sorted lists in python

Tags: python, arrays, merge, sorting

I have a bunch of sorted lists of objects, and a comparison function

```
class Obj :
    def __init__(p) :
        self.points = p
def cmp(a, b) :
    return a.points < b.points

a = [Obj(1), Obj(3), Obj(8), ...]
b = [Obj(1), Obj(2), Obj(3), ...]
c = [Obj(100), Obj(300), Obj(800), ...]

result = magic(a, b, c)
assert result == [Obj(1), Obj(1), Obj(2), Obj(3), Obj(3), Obj(8), ...]
```

what does `magic` look like? My current implementation is

```
def magic(*args) :
    r = []
    for a in args : r += a
    return sorted(r, cmp)
```

but that is quite inefficient. Better answers?

Comment: If they are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464342/combining-two-sorted-lists-in-python

Comment: How big are those lists?  How much time is spent sorting them?  Measure before (and after) you optimize.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python standard library offers a method for it: [`heapq.merge`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge).
As the documentation says, it is very similar to using [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) (but with more limitations); if you cannot live with those limitations (or if you do not use Python 2.6) you can do something like this:

```
sorted(itertools.chain(args), cmp)
```

However, I think it has the same complexity as your own solution, although using iterators should give some quite good optimization and speed increase.

Comment: Using key instead of cmp should be prefered (and shoudl be faster). Python3 does not have cmp parameter anyway.

Comment: Actually, I was just using the same format as OP, but you are absolutely right and *key* should be preferred over *cmp*.

Comment: Well, and the OP's cmp function is wrong and doesn't work. If you're using heapq, you'll have to provide __lt__ etc. methods on your class or use a tuple of (sorting key, object) in your heap instead.

Comment: I think you mean itertools.chain(*args).  What you wrote is equivalent to sorted(iter(args), cmp), which makes little sense.

Comment: If I understand correctly that, sorting concatenated lists is `Θ(n.log n)` of complexity (proposed solution by code example), but merging (of sorted) lists is `Θ(n)`. Not so small difference.

Comment: the code example should be with `heapq.merge`. Using sorted and itertools together does not make much sense. Just write a key function and use either `sorted(a+b+c, key=lambda x: x.points)` for a list or `heapq.merge(a,b,c, key=lambda x: x.points)` for an iterator.

Answer (score 3):

I like Roberto Liffredo's answer. I didn't know about heapq.merge(). Hmmmph.

Here's what the complete solution looks like using Roberto's lead:

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, p) :
        self.points = p
    def __cmp__(self, b) :
        return cmp(self.points, b.points)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%d" % self.points

a = [Obj(1), Obj(3), Obj(8)]
b = [Obj(1), Obj(2), Obj(3)]
c = [Obj(100), Obj(300), Obj(800)]

import heapq

sorted = [item for item in heapq.merge(a,b,c)]
for item in sorted:
    print item
```

Or:

```
for item in heapq.merge(a,b,c):
    print item
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) module. From the documentation: "This module provides support for maintaining a list in sorted order without having to sort the list after each insertion."

```
import bisect

def magic(*args):
    r = []
    for a in args:
        for i in a:
            bisect.insort(r, i)
    return r
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a list, you can use a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure).

The insertion is O(log(n)), so merging a, b and c will be O(n log(n))

In Python, you can use the [`heapq` module](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html).

Comment: +1: Sorting a list in inherently inefficient: prevent the sort by using a smarter structure.

Comment: @OrganicPanda: Did you read the answer? It says that `heapq` amortizes the sorting cost.  That's a smarter structure.  Consider this, too. Accumulating three separate collections seems silly.  Why not accumulate one hash of mutable objects; this can get updated by objects from the other sources.  Now the "comparison" is moot because the objects have all be properly associated with each other without any sorting.

Comment: @S.Lott My apologies - I thought you were suggesting a smarter answer of your own but not explaining it .. my bad

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it would be any quicker, but you could simplify it with:

```
def GetObjKey(a):
    return a.points

return sorted(a + b + c, key=GetObjKey)
```

You could also, of course, use `cmp` rather than `key` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

One line solution using sorted:

```
def magic(*args):
  return sorted(sum(args,[]), key: lambda x: x.points)
```

IMO this solution is very readable.

Using heapq module, it could be more efficient, but I have not tested it. You cannot specify cmp/key function in heapq, so you have to implement Obj to be implicitly sorted.

```
import heapq
def magic(*args):
  h = []
  for a in args:
    heapq.heappush(h,a)
  return [i for i in heapq.heappop(h)
```

Comment: Your heapq method is a mess. You're pushing entire lists instead of their items, and you're ignoring the key. The one liner is cool, though.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I have used heapq just few times and I did not paste that to console to test it. My fault, sorry. Although now I see that Obj object must be defined "sortable" for heapq to work, because you cannot specify cmp/key function in heapq.

Comment: This code is all around a mess. Both snippets have syntax errors, and using sum for concatenating lists is very inefficient. Not to mention that there's operator.attrgetter to replace the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: a fully functioning merge sort for lists (adapted from my sort [here](http://github.com/hughdbrown/algorithm/blob/05307be15669de0541cd4e91c03b610d440b4290/mergesort.py)):

```
def merge(*args):
    import copy
    def merge_lists(left, right):
        result = []
        while left and right:
            which_list = (left if left[0] <= right[0] else right)
            result.append(which_list.pop(0))
        return result + left + right
    lists = list(args)
    while len(lists) > 1:
        left, right = copy.copy(lists.pop(0)), copy.copy(lists.pop(0))
        result = merge_lists(left, right)
        lists.append(result)
    return lists.pop(0)
```

Call it like this:

```
merged_list = merge(a, b, c)
for item in merged_list:
    print item
```

For good measure, I'll throw in a couple of changes to your Obj class:

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, p) :
        self.points = p
    def __cmp__(self, b) :
        return cmp(self.points, b.points)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%d" % self.points
```

- Derive from object
- Pass `self` to `__init__()`
- Make `__cmp__` a member function
- Add a `str()` member function to present `Obj` as string

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question and got some excellent answers:

- [Joining a set of ordered-integer yielding Python iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969709/joining-a-set-of-ordered-integer-yielding-python-iterators)

The best solutions from that question are variants of the merge algorithm, which you can read about here:

- [Wikipedia: Merge Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of a function that runs in O(n) comparisons.

You could make this faster by making a and b iterators and incrementing them.

I have simply called the function twice to merge 3 lists:

```
def zip_sorted(a, b):
    '''
    zips two iterables, assuming they are already sorted
    '''
    i = 0
    j = 0
    result = []
    while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
        if a[i] < b[j]:
            result.append(a[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(b[j])
            j += 1
    if i < len(a):
        result.extend(a[i:])
    else:
        result.extend(b[j:])
    return result

def genSortedList(num,seed):
    result = [] 
    for i in range(num):
        result.append(i*seed)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = genSortedList(10000,2.0)
    b = genSortedList(6666,3.0)
    c = genSortedList(5000,4.0)
    d = zip_sorted(zip_sorted(a,b),c)
    print d
```

However, **heapq.merge** uses a mix of this method and heaping the current elements of all lists, so should perform much better