# Django Querying Question

Tags: django, many-to-many, intersection, django-queryset

If I were to have two different QuerySets in Django, both representing a ManyToMany relation with the same model, how would I find the intersections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge your querysets in a list and next, create a set, you'll convert back to a list :

```
from itertools import chain
merged_qs = chain(queryset1, queryset2) 
intersection_list = list(set(list( merged_qs )))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to avoid the question by using the IN operator to create a subquery:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in

Answer (score 0):

1. order querysets by same set of keys
2. call iterator() on both querysets
3. feed iterators to **intersect** function from this answer:
   [Joining a set of ordered-integer yielding Python iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969709/joining-a-set-of-ordered-integer-yielding-python-iterators)